# Invalid hook call.Hooks can be called inside of the body. I gets this error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
 const startTimer = () => {
    Alert.alert('hye timer started')
    useInterval(() => {
      handleTimer()
    }, 1000);
  };
```

this is function which is called when i press button.

the useInterval is custom hook who's code is as follow:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      const id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

but when i press the button the function is called in which there is a hook which should be called but instead it give an error invalid custom hook. can you tell what is wrong in this code.

Comment: Where is `startTimer` located? Also, please make sure to provide the actual error, instead of bits and pieces of it.

Comment: it is called on press of touchable opacity

Comment: this is actual error i am getting in my console

Comment: You wrote 2 different errors in the title and body of the question. Which is it and what exactly does it say?

Comment: this error is invalid hook call, hooks can only be called inside body of a react function component.

Comment: Ok, that is a different story. And just like it says, it point to the fact that you are trying to use the hook outside of a React function component. Hence why I asked "Where is `startTimer` located?". i.e. - is it inside of an actual function component?

Comment: yes, i want to call hook when button is pressed.

Comment: Please provide the code for the page where `startTimer` is located.

Comment: <View style={styles.containerbtn}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={()=>startTimer()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Start </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Reset </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a hook inside of a function. Thus, the following is not valid.

```js
function foo() {
   useSomeHook();
}
```

A hook can only be called

> [...] from React function components [... and ...]
> from custom Hooks

as defined [by the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). The function `startTimer` is a regular Javascript function and neither a react functional component nor a custom hook.

For your particular case, you could define the `startTimer` function inside the hook itself and export it. Then, call it `onPress`.

```js
export default function useInterval(callback, delay) {
 const savedCallback = useRef();

  const [start, setStart] = useState(false)

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (start) {
      const tick = () => {
          savedCallback.current();
      }
      if (delay !== null) {
        const id = setInterval(tick, delay);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
      }
    }
  }, [delay, start]);

  const startTimer = React.useCallback((shouldStart) => {
    setStart(shouldStart)
  }, []);

  return startTimer;
}
```

You can start and stop it as follows:

```js
export default function App() {

  const startTimer = useInterval(() => console.log("callback"), 1000)
  
  return (
    <View style={{margin:50}}>
      <Pressable onPress={() => startTimer(true)}> <Text>Start</Text></Pressable>
      <Pressable onPress={() => startTimer(false)}> <Text>Stop</Text></Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Now i understand how to handle custom hooks.